# Beamer: Remove subsection bar in header

Tags: beamer, header-footer

In the Antibes `beamer` theme, I want to remove the bar in the header where the name of the subsection is shown, since I have no subsections in my presentation. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 10):

The Antibes theme uses the `tree` outer theme, so you have to modify the corresponding `headline` template:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Antibes}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,colsep=1.5pt]{upper separation line head}
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,%
      leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
      \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
      \ifbeamer@tree@showhooks
        \setbox\beamer@tempbox=\hbox{\insertsectionhead}%
        \ifdim\wd\beamer@tempbox>1pt%
          \hskip2pt\raise1.9pt\hbox{\vrule width0.4pt height1.875ex\vrule width 5pt height0.4pt}%
          \hskip1pt%
        \fi%
      \else%  
        \hskip6pt%
      \fi%
      \insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
% Code for subsections removed here
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{foo}

\subsection{foobar}

\begin{frame}{A frame}
Some text.
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Consider to use a different outer theme, because a tree without branches somewhat defeats the purpose. ;-) A good option is

```
\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I just had to add this `\useoutertheme[subsection=false]{miniframes}` after this `\mode<presentation> {` and it worked, with my current theme.

Comment: however I seem to always get this error `LaTeX Error: Option clash for package beamerouterthememiniframes.`. Can anyone help me resolve this? I already tried placing the line somewhere else...